# Bootstrap dropdown is hidden behind other elements - Stacking Context issue

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Boostrap dropdown is hidden inside other elements. When I try to click on pencil icon it shows dropdown but some other elements are overriding it. I made position of dropdown relative but it increases site of `Div` tag. attaching screenshot.

[image]     
      
         new
        Christeen
        Last modified 4-5-2016 at 23:16 
           
          
             Share 
             Edit 
             Delete

`CSS`

```
.listing-body ul.listbody {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

.listing-body ul.listbody li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    border-top: none;
}

.listing-body .fourthli {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 1%;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'robotoregular';
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 45px;
    color: #333;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 50%;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    display: none;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

Comment: please share some html too. probably it has to do with the "overflow:hidden" in the `.listing-body .fouthli` property. It's not "beneath" just being cropped off completly, otherwise the `z-index:1000` would have worked

Comment: @LordNeo added HTML. Can you suggest me something, Please

Comment: @LordNeo Your solution worked ! Thanks a lot man !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `overflow:hidden` in the `.listing-body .fouthli` was cropping off the dropdown menu. Removing it fixed it.